# xml2js - always return an array for certain nodes

Tags: javascript, xml2js

The NPM package xml2js has the explicitArray option which only puts nodes into an array if there is more than one of them. Sometimes I have XML which only has one instance of a node but I need it in an array. Is there a way to specify a list of node names which should always be placed into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue #216 "Known array values" addresses this question. [The author doesn't want to handle this.](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/issues/216)